# How to using veutify 3 date-picker on Nuxtjs 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

```
<v-date-picker></v-date-picker>
```

[show this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvc0u.png)

i'm using v-model but show this error

```
const date = ref(new Date())
<v-date-picker v-model="date"></v-date-picker>
```

[show this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esIr3.png)

i'm using nuxt 3 and veutify 3.

Comment: there's no special usage required. the code matches the documentation and is correct.  likely the problem is in the installation.  share your package.json and relevant config files, specifically the ones noted in the installation instructions for [vuetify with nuxt 3](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#using-nuxt-3)